I'm getting JS:Agent-EJE [Trj] message on my website
I ran my website through "sucuri" scanner and it showed me a critical risk (https://somewebsite.net/wp-content/themes/rr/plugins/navigation.js?ver=1.0.0)
also on the browser it shows me a warning as shown in the image: screenshot - warning
I tried using WordFence plugin within wordpress to solve the issue but it recommend option to delete the files that flagged as critical, but the problem is I may delete some important files and the website wont work properly.
so can you explain why I'm seeing this warning and how to solve it
FYI I only have access from the cms wordpress
